# Batch Move Files From HDD to User in SSD

Tags: file, batch-file, move

I'm trying to use the move command to move a folder in my HDD ("S:\folder") to my user in my SSD (C:\Users\Me\somewhere") but it returns access denied, I'm pretty sure it is because it sees the folders in my HDD as another user's and stops file transferring from one user to another, is there anyway past this - maybe declaring one of the folders in my HDD as my user's or something.

And if not where else could I move it too in the C drive that isn't protected?

Come on it's been hours :(

Comment: Sounds like an ntfs permission problem.  You should take ownership of s:\folder, or try copying rather than moving if your read access is ok.

Comment: @rojo yeah xcopy works, at least it'll work but I'll still try to find a solution.